# Requirements for using a struct as an STL map key?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

I'm using an STL map with a `struct` for a key.  This is the definition of the map: 
`std::map<Coord2<uint8_t>, MapTile> tile_;`

The definition of the `struct`:

```
template <typename T>
struct Coord2
{
    T x;
    T y;

    bool operator<(const Coord2<T> &coord) const { return (x < coord.x || y < coord.y); }
    bool operator>(const Coord2<T> &coord) const { return (x > coord.x || y > coord.y); }
}
```

Will I experience issues with the map because the comparison?

Comment: It works, but it behaves quite oddly.

Comment: Could you clarify? I think your problem is related to the way in which you implement your operator.

Comment: It doesn't work, that's why it's behaving oddly.  Imagine the following coordinates: `A:(1,-1)` and `B:(-1,1)` A<B because A.y<B.y, and B<A because B.x<A.x

Comment: Exactly: lots of different coordinates will result in returning the same coordinate.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This `operator<` is unsuitable for use with the C++ Standard Library's associative containers.

A comparator must provide a [strict weak ordering](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html), which yours does not.  Consider the following operands that demonstrate its inconsistency:

```
a = { x = 1, y = 0 }
b = { x = 0, y = 1 }
```

Given these inputs, `a < b == true` and `b < a == true`, but `b != a`.

A correct comparison for this type might be:

```
if (x < coord.x)
    return true;

if (coord.x < x)
    return false;

return y < coord.y;
```

(It's certainly possible to write this correct code in a more compact fashion, however I've debugged enough errors caused by incorrectly implemented strict weak orderings that I'd strongly recommend being very explicit in the comparison so that it is clear that it is correct.  With this implementation, it is very clear that we only compare the `y` values if the `x` values compare equal, which is what we want.)

Comment: What if the `x` values of two coordinates are equal?

Comment: If and only if the two `x` values are equal, you compare the `y` values.

Answer (score 13):

For two values James's answer is ideal, for more members it gets complicated, so a simple way to implement a strict weak ordering over multiple values is to create tuples of those values and compare the tuples:

```
 return boost::tie(x, y, z) < boost::tie(coord.x, coord.y, coord.z);
```

All you need to do for that to work is for each member to be LessThanComparable, then `#include <boost/tuple/tuple_comparison.hpp>` and list the members in the same order in each `tie` expression.

In C++11 you can `#include <tuple>` and use `std::tie` instead.

Comparison for tuples is defined to do a lexicographical comparison, so the first elements are compared and if the result is true the comparison is complete and true is returned, otherwise the next elements are compared in the same way, for each pair of elements. This ensures a correct Strict Weak Ordering as long as each element type has a correctly defined `operator<`.

Comment: Despite having used `tie` and `tuple` extensively, I had never considered this!  Thank you for enlightening me!

Answer (score 2):

First a remark: You don't need `operator>`, since `std::map` will only use `operator<` anyway.

However, your `operator<` is *not* suitable for a `std::map` key because it doesn't define a strict weak ordering. Indeed, it doesn't even implement a strict partial ordering, since it violates both transitivity and antisymmetry: Consider the following definitions:

```
coord p = { 2, 2 };
coord q = { 0, 4 };
coord r = { 1, 1 };
```

Nor `p < q` returns `true` because `2 < 4`, `q < r` returns `true` because `0 < 1`, but `p < r` returns `false`. Thus transitivity is violated.

Moreover, not only does `p < q` return true, but so does `q < p`, because `0 < 2`. In other words, according to your operator, each of `p` and `q` would be considered smaller than the other one.